# symfony2 : cannot insert in one-to-one relation merge form

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine

The customer entity has one-to-one relation with credit entity. When I try inserting I get the following error:

*

> Entity of type Jobeet\JobBundle\Entity\Credit is missing an assigned
>   ID for field 'id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity
>   requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist()
>   is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you
>   need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

*

What am I missing ?

**Customer.orm.yml**

```
type: entity
    table: customer
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: true
        address:
            type: string
            length: 255

    oneToOne:
        credit:
            targetEntity: Credit
            mappedBy: customer
            cascade: [persist]
```

**Credit.orm.yml**

```
type: entity
table: credit
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
fields:
    customer_id:
        type: integer
        unique: true
        nullable: false
    credit_name:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
    credit_desc:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true

oneToOne:
    customer:
        targetEntity: Customer
        inversedBy: credit
        joinColumn:
            name: customer_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

**CustomerType.php**

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('address')
            ->add('credit', new CreditType())
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change **Credit.orm.yml** to

```
type: entity
    table: credit
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            unique: true
            column: other_non_conflict_column_name
...
```

Comment: When I persist now I am getting "INSERT INTO credit (customer_id, credit_name, credit_desc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "adfadfasdf", null] Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'customer_id' cannot be null. 

I am getting null value in id.